# How to plot multiple curves with arrows in opposite directions

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need a plot with arrows going to the left on some curves and to the right on others. I have not figured out how to do this within a single Plot command. When I make two plots and try to overlay them with Show, the arrows all point the same direction. Minimum Working Example:

```
P1 = Plot[{
  yh /. {a -> 4, b -> 1},
  yn /. {a -> 2, b -> .002, n -> 3.5}
  }, {x, -10, 10},
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[Table[.03, {5}]],
 PlotStyle -> {Black}] /. Line -> Arrow
P2 = Plot[{
  -yh /. {a -> 4, b -> 1},
  -yn /. {a -> 2, b -> .002, n -> 3.5}
  }, {x, -10, 10},
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
 BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[Table[-.03, {5}]],
 PlotStyle -> {Black}] /. Line -> Arrow
 Show[P1, P2]
```

Notice that the arrows in P2 (which are correct) and in the output of Show do not point the same direction.

Comment: You need to post the code for `yh` and `yn`.

Answer (score 2):

```
yh = b x^(2 ) + a ; yn = b (a x)^(3) + n; (* replace these with your yh and yn *)
ah1 = Arrowheads[Table[.03, {5}]];
ah2 = Arrowheads[Table[-.03, {5}]];
```

Use a single `Plot` with `PlotStyle` specifying the `Arrowheads` for each curve:

```
Plot[{yh /. {a -> 4, b -> 1}, yn /. {a -> 2, b -> .002, n -> 3.5}, 
     -yh /. {a -> 4, b -> 1}, -yn /. {a -> 2, b -> .002, n -> 3.5}}, 
    {x, -10, 10}, 
    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    PlotLegends -> {"yh /.{a -> 4,b ->1}",  "yn /.{a->2,b->.002,n->3.5}", 
    "-yh /.{a->4,b->1}", "-yn /.{a->2,b->.002,n->3.5}"},
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[ah1, Red], Directive[ah1, Green], 
    Directive[ah2, Blue], Directive[ah2, Orange]}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks!! I have never looked deeply enough to figure out the use of Directive. The results of this will show up in the next edition of my textbook.

Comment: @Paul, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.